# Why does nobody care that Natalie steals an identity card?

Tags: plot-explanation, up-in-the-air

In Up in the Air (2009), there is a scene where Natalie Keener (in a black dress in the picture below) steals someone's identity card.

Why does no one care that she is easily stealing an identity card?

[image]

Comment: First, welcome to Movies & TV! Hope you enjoy it here. Second, judging by the picture, it looks very possible that it's just that nobody *noticed/saw* her stealing the card. Is that possible? (Rather than nobody caring about whether she did?)

Comment: I tried to clean up the grammar of your question. If I accidentally changed the meaning, please feel free to undo my changes.

Comment: Also, it's not *exactly* an ID card I'd guess. That looks like a tech conference / show / convention. It's more likely to be a name tag than an ID. Those go missing all the time.